# How to add Navigation Markers as Chapters for my video in tvOS?

Tags: swift, swift3, tvos

### Description:

I'm trying to understand (*the madness*) on how to add navigation markers to my video in tvOS.

Logically it shouldn't be complicated. Specify a list of markers with a chapter starting point, a chapter title, and a thumbnail for that specific video point.

However, I'm having a hard time grasping how to implement this.

### What I've tried:

This is what I believe is the minimum for this to be implemented, however I have no idea why I need all this for it to work. I also have no idea how I'm supposed to set the information.

```
    //In my AVPlayerViewController
    let metadataItem = AVMetadataItem()

    let metadataItemList = [metadataItem]

    let cmTimeStart = CMTimeMake(0, 0)
    let cmTimeDuration = CMTimeMake(10, 1)

    let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: cmTimeStart, duration: cmTimeDuration)

    let timedMetadataGroup = AVTimedMetadataGroup(items: metadataItemList, timeRange: timeRange)
    let timedMetadataGroupList = [timedMetadataGroup]
    let navigationMarkersGroup = AVNavigationMarkersGroup(title: "Chapters", timedNavigationMarkers: timedMetadataGroupList)

    //Already previously initialized avPlayerItem
    avPlayerItem.navigationMarkerGroups.append(navigationMarkersGroup)
```

*(The goal with the code above is to have one chapter shown for my video.)*

### Question:

I'm seeking clarity on how to implement the Navigation Markers as "Chapters" in my video in tvOS. A detailed explanation on what each part is supposed to accomplish would equally be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Introduction

To be able to add chapters the concept isn't as complicated as I had originally thought. You'll need to use the following main classes:

- `AVMetadataItem`
- `AVMutableMetadataItem`
- `AVTimedMetadataGroup`
- `AVNavigationMarkersGroup`

### Part 1: Creating a chapter generating method

To simplify the work, we'll create a method that generates a "chapter" or as you'll see a `AVTimedMetadataGroup` that consists of a `title`, a `description`, and a start time.

The main issue I had was that in Swift2 we could specify the identifier type directly with `AVMetadataItem` **(EDIT: This is factually wrong, in their examples they created a custom class called AVMettadataItem that used AVMutableMetadataItem to generate what they wanted)** which isn't possible anymore with `Swift3`. However, this can be solved with `AVMutableMetadataItem`

For example this is how we create a `AVMutableMetadataItem` for the title of the chapter:

```
let titleItem =  AVMutableMetadataItem()
titleItem.identifier = AVMetadataCommonIdentifierTitle
titleItem.value = title as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)?
```

Each of these items needs to be added to a list that we'll call "items" ( `[AVMetadataItem]` )

Once your list is completed, you'll want to create the `AVTimedMetadataGroup` with the list you just created and the timeRange that will be applied to your video (aka: Where you chapter will start and how long it lasts)

In my case, chapter duration isn't a big deal so I set it to a fixed time (10 seconds).

*The thing that you need to watch out for is, if the `CMTime` is not valid, the chapter does not show up in the list.*

```
private func setupNavigationMarker(title: String, description: String, timeStart: Int64)-> AVTimedMetadataGroup {

    let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: CMTimeMake(timeStart, 1), duration: CMTimeMake(10, 1))

    var items: [AVMetadataItem] = []
    let titleItem =  AVMutableMetadataItem()
    titleItem.identifier = AVMetadataCommonIdentifierTitle
    titleItem.value = title as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)?
    items.append(titleItem)

    let descriptionItem = AVMutableMetadataItem()
    descriptionItem.identifier = AVMetadataCommonIdentifierDescription
    descriptionItem.value = description as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)?
    items.append(descriptionItem)

    return AVTimedMetadataGroup(items: items, timeRange: timeRange)

}
```

### Part 2: Add your chapter to your `AVNavigationMarkerGroup`

Then somewhere in your AVPlayerViewController (like `ViewDidLoad`):

```
var timedMetadataGroupList = [AVTimedMetadataGroup]()

timedMetadataGroupList.append(self.setupNavigationMarker(title: "test1", description: "description test1" , timeStart: 100))
timedMetadataGroupList.append(self.setupNavigationMarker(title: "test2", description: "description test2" , timeStart: 200))
timedMetadataGroupList.append(self.setupNavigationMarker(title: "test3", description: "description test3" , timeStart: 300))

let navigationMarkersGroup = AVNavigationMarkersGroup(title: "Chapters", timedNavigationMarkers: timedMetadataGroupList)

avPlayerItem.navigationMarkerGroups.append(navigationMarkersGroup)
```

### Part 3: Add images to your chapters

Coming soon...

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MediaPlaybackGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/UsingAVKitPlatformFeatures/UsingAVKitPlatformFeatures.html